# How to do the redirect request based on okhttp3 and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using the okhttp3 and retrofit as the android project request framework, and i have a application scene below:

There are two servers in our project with two domain;what we want to do is when connect to one server failed then we reconnect with another server in the one request,so we use the okhttp3 Interceptor like below:

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        int tryCount = 0;//retry times
        int RetryCount = 3;
        while (!response.isSuccessful() && tryCount <= RetryCount) {
            String url = request.url().toString();
            if (!Util.checkNULL(FirstIP) && !Util.checkNULL(SecondIP)) {
                if (url.contains(FirstIP)) {//change url
                    url = url.replace(FirstIP, SecondIP);
                } else if (url.contains(SecondIP)) {
                    url = url.replace(SecondIP, FirstIP);
                }
                Request newRequest = response.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();//recreate request
                tryCount++;//add request count 
                response = chain.proceed(newRequest);//retry the request
            } else {
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

But there is an error with this sentence:

Response response = chain.proceed(request);

This sentence will throw exception when the url can't be connected,so this will not make the retry work as expected, is there any workaround about this?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I make an workaround like below:

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    // try the request
    Response response = doRequest(chain,request);
    int tryCount = 0;
    while (response == null && tryCount <= RetryCount) {
        String url = request.url().toString();
        url = switchServer(url);
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
        tryCount++;
        // retry the request
        response = doRequest(chain,newRequest);
    }
    if(response == null){//important ,should throw an exception here
        throw new IOException();
    }
    return response;
}

private Response doRequest(Chain chain,Request request){
    Response response = null;
    try{
        response = chain.proceed(request);
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return response;
}
```